# Нужна помощь с джанго проектом

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Мне надо создать систему регистрации пользователей, там 4 типа пользователей, Админ1, Админ2, Модератор, Пользователь.
Есть модели и собственная панель управления(админам тоже кастомная), есть формы в кастомном админ панели, не могу реализовать создать(create) и изменение(edit)

вот сам код forms.py:

```
class Admin2Form(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Admin2
    fields = ['name', 'email', 'login', 'parol']
    widgets = {
        'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'login': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'parol': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
    }


def clean_slug(self):
    new_slug = self.cleaned_data['slug'].lower()

    if new_slug == 'create':
        raise ValidationError('Slug error "Create"')
    if Admin2.objects.filter(slug__iexact=new_slug).count():
        raise ValidationError('Virajeniya "{}" yest'.format(new_slug))
    return new_slug
```

views.py
urls.py не получается у меня!

Comment: все решил надо было поспать от того и тупил, mixin ном завершил дела

Comment: Если решил, то надо либо написать ответ и отметить его решением, либо удалить вопрос.

Comment: ок ответ напишу

Comment: так и не написал

Comment: сорян работы было многовато!

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой views.py:

```
#User
class UserProfilCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, ObjectCreateMixin, View):
    model_form = Admin2Form
    template = 'create_form.html'
```

таким будет utils.py:

```
class ObjectCreateMixin:
    model_form = None
    template = None

    def get(self, request):
        form = self.model_form()
        return render(request, self.template, context={'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        bound_form = self.model_form(request.POST)

        if bound_form.is_valid():
            new_obj = bound_form.save()
            return redirect(new_obj)
        return render(request, self.template, context={'form': bound_form})
```

вот такой create_form.html

```
<form action="{% url 'usr_create_url' %}" method="post">

{% csrf_token %} 
<p>name{{ form.name }}</p> 
<p>email{{ form.email }}</p>
<p>login{{ form.login }}</p>
<p>parol{{ form.parol }}</p>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Сохранить</button></form>
```

Comment: Тут эдит забыл но скоро напишу